# OnRequestPermissionsResult is not called in PageRenderer (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-permissions

I have a `VideoCallPageRenderer` like below

```
VideoCallPageRenderer : PageRenderer, Android.Support.V4.App.ActivityCompat.IOnRequestPermissionsResultCallback
{
    public const int REQUEST_MIC = 0;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
          // Other codes
          RequestMicPermission();
    }

        public void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_MIC)
            {
                if (grantResults.Length == 1 && grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
                {

                }
            }
        }

    private void RequestMicPermission()
    {
        Android.Support.V4.App.ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions((Activity)Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, new string[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio }, REQUEST_MIC);
    }

}
```

Here `RequestMicPermission` works fine because I can see the pop up coming on screen asking for permission. But after I allow or deny `OnRequestPermissionsResult` is not called.

Any help? It would be very hard to try to override it in the Activity.

Comment: What's you mean  "But after I allow or deny OnRequestPermissionsResult is not called" ?

Comment: Yes. Although I could not make it work by implementing the interface `IOnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` . Rather I had to override `OnRequestPermissionsResult` in my MainActivity and then invoke a static method in my `VideoCallPageRenderer `. From that I could get a hold of the instance of the active `VideoCallPageRenderer ` to get the whole thing working.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else having an issue here, I was not seeing the OnRequestPermissionsResult being called either.  But I had the debugger attached, the handler wasn't doing anything, and even though the breakpoint was valid, it was never hit.

I finally did a clean and rebuild and voila, the breakpoint was hit.

Just in case someone else was tearing their hair out like myself :).

Comment: Same thing works for OnActivityResult, over which I was also tearing my hair out  yesterday. Thanks so much for this.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers that encountered this problem too, a good approach is abstract the permissions features in a service and register it with Xamarin Form´s Dependencyservice.

You can resolve this service in your renderer, or any non-activity class, to use it. Also resolve it in MainActivity, override OnRequestPermissionsResult, and call yourService.OnPermissionResult to communicate the result.

As Koushik says ActivityCompat.IOnRequestPermissionsResultCallback doesnt work because we call RequestPermissions with reference to MainActivity, so the result is obtained in this activity.

You can see an implementation example in my Github:

[GpsService](https://github.com/HeikkiDev/CursoXamarinDevsDNA_PracticaFinal/blob/master/AppCursoXamarinDevsDNA/AppCursoXamarinDevsDNA/AppCursoXamarinDevsDNA.Android/Services/GpsService.cs)

[MainActivity](https://github.com/HeikkiDev/CursoXamarinDevsDNA_PracticaFinal/blob/master/AppCursoXamarinDevsDNA/AppCursoXamarinDevsDNA/AppCursoXamarinDevsDNA.Android/MainActivity.cs)